# Reprojecting Tifs

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

When I import some geotifs into QGIS, they use a reference of 0, 360. My basemaps are all -180, 180. Both the basemaps and geotifs use the same CRS, WGS84. So the geotifs display starting at 0 on the base maps and only overlap half, so I can't intersect them. How can I reproject the geotifs?

Answer (score 1):

Reprojecting can be done by going to Raster then Projection and then Transform.Hope it helps.